# IOError "Too many open files" while using savefig() in a loop

Tags: matplotlib, plot, figure

I have a little issue with matplotlib. While trying to save some figures in a loop hundred times with `savefig()`, it finally ends with the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'test_421.png'
```

I have checked that I close every `figure` after saving it, but it doesn't seem to be efficient.

Here is a code sample to illustrate how I get this error:

```
def displayFig(input, display, savePath):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22, 5))
    # add some subplots, axis and colorbars...
    if display:
        plt.show()
    else:
        plt.savefig(savePath, dpi = 100)
    plt.close(fig)

for i, inp in enumerate(inpArray):
    savePath = 'test_%d.png' % i
    displayFig(inp, False, savePath)
```

Why is this error raised? Could it be a multi-threading issue or a memory leak?

Comment: Maybe just raise the ulimit.

Comment: I'm not on a Linux environment but your guess is interesting. As I'm doing pure research for now, my algorithm is not optimized yet and might sometimes be greedy, especially for big sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your version of matplotlib. I believe from matplotlib v1.2.0 this was addressed (by this PR https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1466/).